# Loop through json array and add to each object using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Suppose I have the following JSON array: (here's the first 3 in an array of 100)

```
var data = [
                {
                    "percent_change_1h": "2.19",
                    "percent_change_24h": "-1.07",
                    "percent_change_7d": "-7.2",
                },
                {
                    "percent_change_1h": "1.96",
                    "percent_change_24h": "-2.13",
                    "percent_change_7d": "-11.64",
                },
                {
                    "percent_change_1h": "9.21",
                    "percent_change_24h": "18.31",
                    "percent_change_7d": "18.3",
                }
            ]
```

How can I loop through this data, and add an object to each one of the datasets so after the loop is executed it would look like this:

```
var data = [
                {
                    "percent_change_1h": "2.19",
                    "percent_change_24h": "-1.07",
                    "percent_change_7d": "-7.2",
                    "new_key": "newvalue"
                },
                {
                    "percent_change_1h": "1.96",
                    "percent_change_24h": "-2.13",
                    "percent_change_7d": "-11.64",
                    "new_key": "newvalue"
                },
                {
                    "percent_change_1h": "9.21",
                    "percent_change_24h": "18.31",
                    "percent_change_7d": "18.3",
                    "new_key": "newvalue"
                }
            ]
```

I have messed around with a `for key in data` loop as well as a `forEach` function and I can't quite get it.

Comment: If you tried `for key in data` then you are already 90% of the way there. The remaining 10% is really easy to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop will do. Try the handy `for..of` syntax:

```
for (const o of data) o.new_key = "newvalue";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `map()` :

```
data = data.map(d => ({...d, new_value: "newvalue"}));
```

```js
var data = [
  {"percent_change_1h": "2.19",},
  {"percent_change_1h": "1.96",}
];

data = data.map(d => ({...d, new_value: "newvalue"}));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looping trow the object then add the newval see this function :

```js
var data = [
                {
                    "percent_change_1h": "2.19",
                    "percent_change_24h": "-1.07",
                    "percent_change_7d": "-7.2",
                },
                {
                    "percent_change_1h": "1.96",
                    "percent_change_24h": "-2.13",
                    "percent_change_7d": "-11.64",
                },
                {
                    "percent_change_1h": "9.21",
                    "percent_change_24h": "18.31",
                    "percent_change_7d": "18.3",
                }
            ]

function addValue(data,vals)
{
  for(var inc = 0;inc < data.length ; inc++)
  {
    data[inc]['newval'] = vals;
   }
   return data;
}

console.log(addValue(data,'newval'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    bottom: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
```